# Linux installation for the connected launchpad TM4C1294

Tags: embedded-linux

I want to know if the TM4C1294 supports Linux so I can start looking to install it into the device, and develop some kernel modules and drivers for this device.

Comment: this board and CPU lack some key capabilities required to run full-featured OS, like Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for two reasons.

- No MMU.
- Not enough RAM.

ucLinux (a variant for large microcontrollers) might be an option. This depends if someone has done a port for that target. You will still need to attach more (external) RAM.